# Getting center of screen

Tags: c#, winforms

*Note: using c# windows form in visual studio 2017*

The below code is now correct for future use.

I am trying to develop code that will help me detect in which quadrant the mouse is each 0.5 second. I first tried with 0 but I discovered that there is no negative value for the mouse position in c#. So instead I thought I would use the width and the height that I calculated with:

```
 public void setScreenSize()
 {
    int W = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    int H = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    Console.WriteLine("Height is: " + H + "width is: " + W);
 }
```

full code here:

```
public partial class Recording : Form
{

    private System.Timers.Timer mousePositionTimer;

    int W, H;


    public Recording()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Recording_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setScreenSize();
        SetTimer(mousePositionTimer, 250,OnTimedMousePositionEvent);

    }

    public void setScreenSize()
    {
        W = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        H = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        Console.WriteLine("Height is: " + H + "width is: " + W);

    }


    private void SetTimer(System.Timers.Timer t, int millis, ElapsedEventHandler f)
    {
        t = new System.Timers.Timer(millis);
        t.Elapsed += f;
        t.AutoReset = true;
        t.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimedMousePositionEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        record.addMousePosition(W,H,MousePosition.X,MousePosition.Y);
    }



}
```

Then, I used the following to detect the quadrant:

```
//getting position of mouse in a given quadrant
public static class record
{
     public static void addMousePosition(int w, int h, int x, int y)
     {
         if (x > w/2 && y > h/2)
             mousePositions.Add(1);
         else if (x > w/2 && y <= h/2)
             mousePositions.Add(2);
         else if (x <= w/2 && y <= h/2)
             mousePositions.Add(3);
         else if (x <= w/2 && y > h/2)
             mousePositions.Add(4);
     }
}
```

However, when I print my list I always get Quadrant 1 . Is there a better way to get the center of the screen so I can do my conditions in a correct manner?

Please remember that I am trying to do this outside the form and not necessarily on it.

Comment: Please show us where you use the `addMousePosition()` Method. It also looks that you set your ScreenCenter only to the local `W` and `H` of your `setScreenSize()`. So it could be that you call your check with a default 0 at `w` and `h`, which will result in Quadrant 1.

Comment: I am missing some variables in the code provided. The first function setScreenSize fills two local variables. The addMousePosition uses four parameters, but it is unknown where these come from. Especially the second is of interest, since that defines the if/else in the routine

Comment: setScreenSize() is called on form load

Comment: addMousePosition in inside a static class and it is receiving W and H that are set by setScreenSize();

Comment: Are the screensize values you get correct? Make sure the application is declared as DPI Aware. How are you getting your mouse position?

Comment: Mouse.X and Mouse.Y

Comment: That's the point. You are only setting local variables and no class members.You Approach should work when you define fields or properties for `H` and `W` and use them in `setScreenSize()`

Comment: I updated the question to include the full code

Comment: Replace the `int H` and the `int W` in your method by just `H` and `W`.

Comment: oops you are right! I wonder why it didn't complain about it

Comment: @SaraKat: The reason I suggest the edit was, that you edit your question so the problem you have will not occure anymore so the question as it no is does not show the problem you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope issue?

```
public void setScreenSize()
{
    int W = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    int H = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    Console.WriteLine("Height is: " + H + "width is: " + W);
}
```

to

```
public void setScreenSize()
{
    W = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    H = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    Console.WriteLine("Height is: " + H + "width is: " + W);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create 4 `Rectangle`s then use `Rectangle.Contains` to check where the mouse is:

```
Rectangle topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight;

void CalculateQuadrants(Form mainForm)
{
     Screen myScreen = Screen.FromControl(mainForm);
     Rectangle area = myScreen.WorkingArea;
     topLeft = new Rectangle(area.Left, area.Top, area.Right/2, area.Bottom/2);
     topRight = new Rectangle(area.Right/2, area.Top, area.Right/2, area.Bottom/2);
     bottomLeft = new Rectangle(area.Left, area.Bottom/2, area.Right/2, area.Bottom/2);
     bottomRight = new Rectangle(area.Right/2, area.Bottom/2, area.Right/2, area.Bottom/2);
}
```

Then you can do a simple .Contains to check the mouse pointer:

```
public static void addMousePosition(Point mousePosition)
{
    if (topLeft.Contains(mousePosition))
        mousePositions.Add(1);
    else if (topRight.Contains(mousePosition))
        mousePositions.Add(2);
    else if (bottomLeft.Contains(mousePosition))
        mousePositions.Add(3);
    else if (bottomRight.Contains(mousePosition))
        mousePositions.Add(4);
}
```

Comment: I need it to work as screen size , the form will be minimized while it detects them

Comment: Screen.FromControl will get the bounds of the screen that 'most' of the form is running on, irrespective of how many screens are attached.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up my comments from above:

When you are calling `setScreenSize()` from `OnFormLoad()` you will only set the local variables `W` and `H` you defined in your methods.

```
public void setScreenSize()
{
    int W = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    int H = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    Console.WriteLine("Height is: " + H + "width is: " + W);
}
```

So these variables will hide your fields you have declared in the

```
public partial class Recording : Form
{
    private System.Timers.Timer mousePositionTimer;

    int W, H;

    ...
}
```

So since the class fields are not initialized they have their `default(int)` value `0`.

When you now call your `addMousePosition()` you will always use the default `0` instead the real values you stored in the local `int H` and `int W`

```
private void OnTimedMousePositionEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    record.addMousePosition(W,H,MousePosition.X,MousePosition.Y);
}

public static void addMousePosition(int w, int h, int x, int y)
{
    if (x > w/2 && y > h/2)
        mousePositions.Add(1);
     else if (x > w/2 && y <= h/2)
         mousePositions.Add(2);
     else if (x <= w/2 && y <= h/2)
         mousePositions.Add(3);
     else if (x <= w/2 && y > h/2)
         mousePositions.Add(4);
 }
```

and so your code will `Add(1)` most of the time. Only in the upper left corner of your screen you should get in the `Add(3)` branch.

So removing the `int` in the front of the local `W` and `H` will fix the issue.

```
public void setScreenSize()
{
    W = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    H = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    Console.WriteLine("Height is: " + H + "width is: " + W);
}
```

For clarification I recommend to use `this.`:

```
public void setScreenSize()
{
    this.W = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    this.H = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    Console.WriteLine("Height is: " + this.H + "width is: " + this.W);
}
```

---

*Site Node:*

> oops you are right! I wonder why it didn't complain about it

*I thought also that VS2017 would give a hint about that but it didn't.
Resharper provides a hint:*

> *Local Variable `H` hides field `int Recording.H`*